# Margins trouble, top margin goes on top of bottom margin

Tags: css, margin

So let's say I had several `<div>`s, each having a `margin-top` and a `margin-bottom`. I would expect these elements to be arranged one after the other: `Top Margin -> Div -> Bottom Margin` for each one. [However, the top margin is "going over the bottom margin"](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/Uw5n2/) (fiddle). So the distance between each element is just the `margin-top`.

I've found a way to fix this using `float:left;`, however I must **not** use this property, neither absolute positioning.

PS: If you can't see the problem in the fiddle, use something like Chrome's console.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is the problem here hehe. I think the css is behaving as expected. Here is the margin as per my observation. `20px Margin -> Div -> 30px Margin -> Div -> 30px Margin -> Div -> 30px Margin -> Div -> 10px Margin`

Comment: The CSS **is** applied, but visually it looks as if it wasn't. BTW, which browser are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are seeing is called margin collapse. It is the correct behaviour according to the standard.

[Margin does not push down another margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642036/margin-does-not-push-down-another-margin-css)